# Swift Error Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am writing script where I am attaching a variable in gamescene.swift to a sprite in gamescene.sks. I have done this before, but now I am getting an error that I don't understand.

I have no Idea what to do here, so please send help.

```
var p      = SKSpriteNode() // this is the declaration
```

below is in didMoveTo()

```
    p.name = "p"
           p = self.childNode(withName: "p") as! SKSpriteNode
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-06-25 12:50:45.259190-0700 Select[25918:1085668] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

***** I found out that the error wasn't in this script, I had weird declarations in my GameViewController

Comment: Put a break point in `p = self.childNode(withName: "p") as! SKSpriteNode` and in the debugger write:
`po self.childNode(withName: "p")`


If that is nil, a child node named p do not exist, so, if you use **!** to force the cast `as! SKSpriteNode`, the app crash trying to access to nil value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is crashing because the scene does not have a child node that has the name `p` and is a sprite node. Without more information there's no way to know why there is no child node `p` in the scene.

If you are setting the value of a sprite in your code to a sprite in the SKS file, make sure the name you supply to `self.childName` matches the sprite's name in the SKS file.

```
p = self.childNode(withName: "SpriteNameInSKSFile") as! SKSpriteNode
```

If you are building a sprite in code, call the `addChild` function to add the sprite as a child of the scene.

```
self.addChild(p)
```

By the way you should use a more descriptive variable name than `p`.